# Generic/Text only printer drivers for x64 and x86, installation in Win server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, drivers, network-printer, shared-printers

While migrating printers from a 2003 server to 2008R2(x64) using print management I realized that few printers use "Generic/Text only" drivers. Since it migrated using print management it migrated the driver too, but only x64 version got migrated. I want to add x86 version to be installed since the server hosts few x86 PC's too.

NOTE: In some cases of migration both the x86 and x64 drivers are installed for "Generic/ Text only" but the driver versions are different which creates a problem for clients